# How can I modify this function so that if the parameters of the function are specific structs it returns the struct with the bigger integer?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, max

I have to modify this max function such that if it deals with a `struct Student`,it will return the maximum grade.
Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
typedef struct Student {
    char* name;
    int grade;
}Student;
template<typename  T>
T Max(T var1, T var2) {
    if (sizeof(T) == sizeof(Student))
        return(var1.grade > var2.grade) ? var1 : var2;
    return (var1 > var2) ? var1 : var2;
}
int main() {

    int i = 39;
    int j = 20;
    cout << "Max(i,j)=" << Max(i, j)<<endl;
    double f1 = 13.5;
    double f2 = 20.7;
    cout << "Max(f1,f2)=" << Max(f1, f2) << endl;
    string s1 = "Hello";
    string s2 = "World";
    cout << "Max(s1,s2)="<<Max(s1,s2) << endl;
    Student first_student;
    Student second_student;
    first_student.name = new char[30];
    second_student.name = new char[30];
    strcpy(first_student.name, "Popescu David");
    strcpy(second_student.name,"Gigel Petrovici");
    first_student.grade = 7;
    second_student.grade = 6;
    cout << "Max(student1,student2)=" << Max(first_student, second_student).grade << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I get these bugs:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OOP, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LastTODO.cpp
1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\oop\oop\lasttodo.cpp(11): error C2228: left of '.grade' must have class/struct/union
1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\oop\oop\lasttodo.cpp(11): note: type is 'T'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\oop\oop\lasttodo.cpp(22): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T Max<int>(T,T)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\oop\oop\lasttodo.cpp(11): error C2039: 'grade': is not a member of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>d:\visual studio\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xstring(4373): note: see declaration of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\oop\oop\lasttodo.cpp(28): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T Max<std::string>(T,T)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=std::string
1>        ]
1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\oop\oop\lasttodo.cpp(12): error C2676: binary '>': 'T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Student
1>        ]
1>c:\users\dragos\source\repos\oop\oop\lasttodo.cpp(38): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T Max<Student>(T,T)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Student
1>        ]
1>Done building project "OOP.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This is begging for a specialization, if not an outright overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++17 you can use `if constexpr` to request the following line

```
    return(var1.grade > var2.grade) ? var1 : var2;
```

compiles only if `T` is `Student`:

```
template<typename  T>
T Max(T var1, T var2) {
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, Student> )
        return(var1.grade > var2.grade) ? var1 : var2;
    else
        return (var1 > var2) ? var1 : var2;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e4ZmkP)

---

Another possibility is to define primary version of `Max` as:

```
template<typename  T>
T Max(T var1, T var2) {
    return (var1 > var2) ? var1 : var2;
}
```

and provide specialization for `Student` struct:

```
template<>
Student Max<Student>(Student var1, Student var2) {
    return(var1.grade > var2.grade) ? var1 : var2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.One more thing:Can you tell me how I can enable the C++ 17 compiler on VS 2017?I know there are some answers on this topic on SO,but they seem hard for me to get them and I'd prefer some more "on-point",easier and quicker to understand answers.

Comment: `Project` - `Properties/Settings` - `C/C++` - `Language` - and in option `C++ standard` you need to select `/std:c++latest` (preferred) or `/std:c++17` (in this case - VS17 I don't know if it is supported).